# Setting subviews to nil in a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, swift2

I'm trying to remove subviews and the view from its superview and also set them to nil. I  noticed that the method `removeFromSuperview` does not set them to nil, which is not what I want. The error I get is at the line         `loadingViewSubviews[i] = nil`. It says :  **Cannot assign through subscript, loadingViewSubviews is immutable**. How can I overcome this?

This is the code I am using in my `viewDidDisappear`

```
override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    var loadingViewSubviews = loadingView.subviews
    if loadingView != nil{
        for var i = 0; i < loadingViewSubviews.count; ++i{
            loadingViewSubviews[i].removeFromSuperview()
            loadingViewSubviews[i] = nil
        }
        loadingView.removeFromSuperview()
        loadingView = nil
    }
}
```

**EDIT: this code creates loadingView and it's subviews**

```
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
var activityLabel:UILabel!
var loadingView: UIView!




func processingIAP() {
        if loadingView == nil{
            activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge)
            activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
            let labelRect = CGRectMake(activityIndicator.frame.width+6, 0, 200, activityIndicator.frame.height+12)
            activityLabel = UILabel(frame: labelRect)
            activityLabel.text = "Accessing store..."
            activityLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            activityLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
            activityLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            let rect = CGRectMake(sceneView.frame.width/2.0-(activityIndicator.frame.width/2.0 + activityLabel.frame.width/2.0+12), sceneView.frame.height/2.0-(activityIndicator.frame.height/2.0), activityIndicator.frame.width + activityLabel.frame.width+24, activityIndicator.frame.height+12)
            loadingView = UIView(frame: rect)
            loadingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            self.sceneView.addSubview(loadingView)
            loadingView.addSubview(activityIndicator)
            loadingView.addSubview(activityLabel)
            loadingView.layer.cornerRadius = 3
            loadingView.layer.borderWidth = 3
            loadingView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            activityIndicator.frame.origin = CGPointMake(6, (loadingView.frame.height-activityIndicator.frame.height)/2.0)
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
        }else{
            activityLabel.text = "Accessing store..."
            activityIndicator.startAnimating()
            activityLabel.frame.origin.x += activityIndicator.frame.width
            activityLabel.frame.size.width -= activityIndicator.frame.width
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to set them all to nil?

Comment: Why do you want to set it nil ? remove fromSuperview would be suffitient

Comment: I dont want them hanging around since they are not used often. Memory saving I guess

Comment: but if your view will disappear, the subviews will automaticly disappear.... so no need for removing them. If they still stay in the memory, than you have a strong cicle somewhere

Comment: Oh, nice catch. Thank you for that. I am also calling this in other methods so I will do that there

Comment: ok great, i wrote an answer with some points where strong cycle is happen. If you found it, would be great to hear it :)

Comment: Oh i guess I do have a strong cycle. loadingView persist. I'have seen that before, basically everytime the VC presentes a VC and than I go back to the preseneingVC. The presenting VC always stays the same. So far I thought this is the excpected behaviour.

Comment: ou can check a strong cycle if you write in your Controller a deinit and Log something, if its logged in the console. Then there is no strong cycle :)

Comment: @krompir2 It depends on your requirements. Why do you need to have strong reference or weak reference. My answer is just let you do manually destroy subviews. BUT if you presenting VC, it is usually weak reference and get value using delegate.

Comment: @krompir2: if you need hel, than update you questions and add some code :)

Comment: I added the code that creates the loadingView and it's subviews. It looks like that I create a strong cycle when I set the labelRect. Is that correct?

Comment: on your posted code i dont see any strong cycle. To debug you code for it. Write a deinit with logging something. than put on your viewDidLoad in the row after supoer.viewDidLoad() a return; than close the ViewController in your simulator. Now check if your deinit logged something. this should log now... if not, than check the viewDidAppear also, means put return in it and try again. somewhere it should log, than you move your return after the next codes in the functions and try as long you deinit is logging. if it stops loggin, you found the strong reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have references to your subviews, it never destroyed itself even remove from the superview.

You can do this way, but in objective c:

```
while (self.subviews.count > 0) {
   id view = [self.subviews lastObject];
   [view removeFromSuperview];
   view = nil;
}
```

Comment: if its not destroying alone, than something else is wrong. Well you could remove them programticly, but its better to fix the problem of the reference,

Comment: It depends on the specific requirements. If subviews are all weak reference then it will destroy itself, but sometimes developer need to handle manually like destroy it himself and also hoping hold reference.

Comment: hmm could be, i never had the need to do it. But if there is a reason it would be cool to know it :)

Answer (score 2):

if you remove the loadingview from its superview, then all its subview get released as well. No need to iterate through all subviews like this:

```
for subview:UIView in self.view.subviews {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: oh nice, didnt know that. Thanks

Comment: NO, it is not necessarily TRUE. if you have reference in the subview, it never destroyed itself even remove from superview.

Comment: If he keeps strong references somewhere else, arc will keep the objects alive of course. He didn't show any code hinting on this though. If we argue about maybe code then why not include C pointer to the fun? :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to set them nil because `loadingViewSubviews[i].removeFromSuperview()` will already remove that subview from superView.

One example for you:

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var loadingView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var l1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var l2: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var loadingViewSubviews = loadingView.subviews

        if loadingView != nil{

            for var i = 0; i < loadingViewSubviews.count; ++i{
                loadingViewSubviews[i].removeFromSuperview()
            }
            loadingView.removeFromSuperview()
            loadingView = nil
        }
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    @IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
        print(l1)
        print(l2)
    }
}
```

In above example at start all the labels will remove with `loadingViewSubviews[i].removeFromSuperview()` and now when you press button then you will get crash error like:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

At line:

```
print(l1)
```

Because that label is no longer available in view because it is removed from start.

Comment: Oh you misunderstood the question but you make a valid point. Thanks. I tried to set the views to nil, but they persist. They are only removed from superview

Answer (score 1):

If you are in viewDidDisappear you dont need to remove all subViews manually. This should happen automaticly. If not, than you have a strong cylcle somewhere. The right way would be to fix that strong cycle.

Therere could be some points where you created one:

1. One of your views holds a property of your Controller. If yes, put this property to weak 
   Example:
   `weak var controller : Controller`
2. You controller is called in a block and this block is not finished. If that happens fix it with
3. You observer a Notification with you controller as observer. If so you can fix it with removing the obserer in the deinit function

Example:

```
deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}
```

Example:

```
aFunctionThatHasABlock() { [weak self] parameterOfSomethingIfThere in
    guard let s = self else { return } // or the controller property
    s.doSomething() // If s is not there it will dont do it :)
}
```

To check of you have a strong reference just write the deinit function and Log something:

```
deinit {
    NSLog("Deinit")
}
```

Comment: about deinit function. Where exactly do I need to declare it? I added it inside VC declaration. It doesn't get called but I think I do have s strong reference cycle

Comment: yes its placed correct. If its not called after dismissing the controller, than you can be 100% sure, that you have a strong cycle

Comment: i updated my post with one more strong cycle posibility

Comment: hmmm, the view contoller in question is the initial view controller. It never gets dismissed, you can only drill deeper in its hierarchy.. How can I handle that situation?

Comment: if your ViewController is never dismissed, how can you cal viewDidDisapper in the Controller? This only happens if the controller gets dismissed

Comment: there is a method called dismissViewControllerAnimated: that dismisses a presented view controller.  I see that your use of word dismiss has nothing to do with it

Comment: no i mean that funciton. If you call dismissViewControllerAnimated, than it will dismiss the currentView controller or not? Well, we misunderstanding. Cann you provice a screen of your hirachy? So i know better what you mean. The point is, that the controller, that will be dismissed, has to call deinit when its finished. if this controller dont calls it, than its still in the memory

Comment: absolutely. The presented VC is dismissed with by calling self.dismissViewControllerAnimated. The initial VC however is not the same as presented VC. dismissViewControllerAnimated will never bi called because there is no way to get higher up the VC hierarchy. I really appreciate your help. I think you got me onto something.I think i will do some guided tutorial on deinit subject.